# Utilizar aparición como referencia Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Necesito poder utilizar la aparición como referencia para el siguiente código de tal forma que si un div aparece a los 1000px de scroll desaparezca 500px después, deben ser independientes una acción de la otra para poder hacer distintas combinaciones. Gracias.

```js
$(window).scroll(function()  {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000 )  {
      $(".topmenu").fadeIn();   // > 100px from top - show div
    }
    else {
     $(".topmenu").fadeOut();    // <= 100px from top - hide div
    }
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2000) { //use `this`, not `document`
        $('.height600').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.youdiclass{position:fixed; display:none;width:100px; height:100px; background:red;}
#back{width:300px; height:500px;background:blue; margin:auto;}
.height600{}
.topmenu{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255,246,0,1.00);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class=" topmenu height600">
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div id="back">
</div>
<div id="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
```

Comment: El html que pones es "inválido". En un documento los `id` deben ser únicos. Te recomiendo que en lugar de usar `id="back"` uses `class="back"` o similar y en tus estilos `.back` en lugar de `#back`. Lee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apunte, lo pondré en práctica :)

Comment: De nada. Eso también se puede resumir en: Usa `id` para **id**entificar y `class` para **class**ificar tus elementos. ;)

Comment: La pregunta me parece un poco confusa y no termino de comprender la relación entre pregunta y código. ¿Es el menú lo que quieres que aparezca/desaparezca?¿Qué es lo que falla en el código de arriba?

Comment: Sí Alvaro, lo que quiero es que la segunda acción (que hace que desaparezca el menú en este caso) haga desaparecer el menú después de 500 px (por ejemplo) después de aparecer y no desde el borde superior de la ventana.

Comment: ¿Y quieres que aparezca múltiples veces a lo largo de la página o sólo una (en 1000px desapareciendo en 1500px)?

Comment: Quiero que la acción de desaparecer tras una cantidad de scroll tome como referencia el punto en el que el div aparece. Si me dieses el truco para ambos casos me vendría bien para aprender

Comment: Entonces por ejemplo si aparece en el 1200, desparecerá en el 1700. Pero si el usuario vuelve a hacer scroll, volverá a aparecer el menu (por ejemplo en el 1800) para desaparecer si sigue haciendo scroll (en el 2300). Por eso pregunto si quieres que el menú sólo aparezca-desaparezca una vez o varias veces en la página

Comment: En ese caso que solo aparezca una vez. Podría ser muy confuso y descontrolado sino.

Comment: Ok, ¿y que pasa si el scroll es menor de 1000px?¿debería estar visible o no?

Comment: No debería, solo aparecer en 1000 y desaparecer tras avanzar 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que el menú (o cualquier otro elemento) aparezca llegado a un scroll y que desaparezca después de X pixels, basándote en la clase que tenga, te recomendaría que hicieras algunos cambios:

- No utilices clases, utiliza los atributos `data-*`.
- Podrías usar dos atributos `data-*`:

  - `data-in`: el número de pixels cuando se mostrará el elemento
  - `data-out`: el número de pixels cuando se esconderá el elemento
- Cuando se haga scroll, comprueba los elementos que contengan esos atributos y muéstralos/escóndelos según corresponda (el elemento debería ser visible si cumple el siguiente requerimiento: data-in < scroll < data-out).

Así quedaría el código con esos cambios. He añadido dos menús con diferente contenido y diferentes `data-in` y `data-out` para que puedas ver como se muestran/esconden cuando llegan a los pixels indicados:

```js
$(window).scroll(function()  {

  // comprobar todos los elementos que tengan el atributo data-in
  $("[data-in]").each(function() {
    
    // si cumplen con data-in < scroll < data-out, los mostramos
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > parseInt($(this).data("in")) && $(window).scrollTop() < parseInt($(this).data("out")) )  {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    }
    // si no, los escondemos
    else {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.youdiclass{position:fixed; display:none;width:100px; height:100px; background:red;}
.back{width:300px; height:500px;background:blue; margin:auto;}
.height600{}
.topmenu{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255,246,0,1.00);
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="topmenu" data-in="1000" data-out="1500">A</div>
<div class="topmenu" data-in="2000" data-out="2500">B</div>
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
<div class="back">
</div>
<div class="back" style="background:green";>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto no soluciona mi problema, yo quisiera lo siguiente, imaginemos dos clases: In100 (que muestra el div tras 100px) y Out500 (que esconde el div tras avanzar 500px) si hubiese una tercera clase In1000 podría combinarla con Out500 y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Tienes que añadir más y mejores detalles a tus preguntas, porque nosotros no podemos adivinar cosas como esa (es la primera vez que haces referencia a algo como in100 o out500). Al menos ahora creo que sé por dónde quieres que vaya el asunto. Quieres añadir algo que indique cuándo se debe mostrar el div y por cuánto, ¿correcto?

Comment: Sí Alvaro, perdona por la confusión. A veces la falta de conocimiento provoca esto, probablemente yo no veo tantos matices posibles u opciones en la resolución de mis problemas. Quiero que diga cuándo y por cuánto en referencia a ese cuando y no al total de la página (si fuese tiempo que aparezca a los 10 segundos y desaparezca 2 segundos después).

Comment: @IvanSoler He cambiado la respuesta, mira a ver si esta se ajusta mejor

Comment: Increíble @AlvaroMontoro es mejor de lo que esperaba. Muchísimas gracias ! Aunque preferiría hacerlo con clases para poder modificarlo todo desde la hoja de java cada vez que me parezca.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "_para poder modificarlo todo desde la hoja de java cada vez que me parezca_"? Igual que cambias la clase puedes cambiar el valor de los atributos `data-*`, no debería haber ninguna diferencia ni ningún problema. Además, usar clases para esto genera problemas adicionales: tendrías que comprobar qué clase se ha incluído (algo que no es tan trivial, especialmente si quieres usar cualquier número), se complicaría el código, sería más difícil de leer y mantener...

Comment: Utilizaría intervalos de valores, no cualquier número. Lo de la hoja de "Java" me refiero a que podría cambiar los valores desde ahí si varias hojas de html toman datos de ella cambiando todo a la vez.
En este momento estoy intentado hacerlo mediante comprobar si el div en cuestión es visible y utilizando la variable Y en referencia a la altura origen pero no logro desentrañarlo...

Comment: Ok. Personalmente creo que usar clases para eso es complicarse la vida con algo que puede hacerse de manera mucho más simple... pero es sólo mi opinión.